# Windows 7 Reinstallation Issue

Tags: windows-7, reinstall

What is the easiest way, if possible, to reinstall Windows 7 without losing files, photos etc. on the same drive (C).

Comment: The only way to do what you want is to perform an in-place upgrade within Windows 7.

Comment: So basically load new on top of old? I do not wish to keep existing programs as I can recover MalwareBytes etc.

Comment: An in-place upgrade will require you to reinstall software.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the ONLY way at this point to install W7 without loosing files, photos and etc on the same drive is to backup your data to an external drive and freshly install or I would suggest simply purchasing a new drive, fresh install windows 7 on that, install the current drive as secondary to be able to retain your files to recover and use as a secondary drive.  If you have registered programs you've purchased, you need to back up all of those proprietary files that belong to the application as well.

No, you cannot simply copy and paste that will not work with apps, just promotes problems.  No, you can't get the jump off and copy registry keys either.  You gotta bite the bullet, rage and rebuilt. You were given an opportunity years ago to roll back.  I too wish I could but honestly, it's time to upgrade regardless.